# How to prove that $\Bbb R$ is a subset of $f(\Bbb{R})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

For $f:\Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ Prove that $f(x) = 2x +|x|$ is surjective.

I know this is done by setting 
$$\Bbb{R} \subseteq 2x +|x|$$

I know that $\Bbb{R} \subseteq2x$ is true since $x$ comes from $\Bbb{R}$. But the $|x|$ throws me off. Any ideas? Thanks in Advance

Edit: I know the formatting of this question is weird, but this is the way the question was presented to me.

Comment: One might notice that if $x \geq 0$, then $f(x) = 3x$ and if $x \leq 0$, then $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Such a thing like $\mathbb{R} \subset 2x$ does not mean anything. $\mathbb{R}$ is a set and $x$ a number.

Comment: This "notation" is atrocious. if you mean to say that the *range* of the function $f$ contains all of $\mathbb R$, say that. Writing nonsense symbols does not help anybody.

Answer (score 1):

surjective in this case means that for every $y \in \Bbb R$ there exists $x \in \Bbb R$ such that $2x + |x| = y$.

Now let's say you are given $y \in \Bbb R$ and you want to find such an $x$.
If $y> 0$ choose $x = \frac y3.$  Note that in this case $x >0$ and hence
$$
2x + |x| = 2 \frac y3  + \frac y3 = y.
$$

If on the other hand $y < 0$ choose $x = y < 0$. Then
$$
2x + |x| = 2y - y = y.
$$

Hence $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

Surjective.

Need to show:

For $y \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a $x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(x)=y.$

Let $y \in.\mathbb{R}.$

0) $y=0$, then $f(x=0)=0$.

1)$y >0.$

$f(x)=2x+|x| =y$  implies $x >0$(Why?)

Hence $2x+x=y$, or $x=y/3$.

Check: $f(x=y/3)= 2(y/3)+y/3 =y$.

2) $y <0$:

$f(x)=2x+|x|= y$  implies $x <0$ (Why?)

$2x -x =y$; or $x=y$.

Check:

$f(x=y)= 2y -y= y$.

Hence surjective.